# How to check equal Names in String Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement

I have an array (`temp3`) of names.

I need determine if any name is equal to another name in the array, without repeating comparisons.

This is what I have so far, thanks.

```
for(int m=0; m<3; m++){
    for(int n=0; n<3; n++){
        if(m!=n){
            if(temp3[m]==temp3[n]){
                System.out.println("Yes");
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i< strings.length;i++){        // Pick a string
  for(int j=i+1; j<strings.length;j++){       // Loop on all strings starting from i+1
         if(strings[i].equals(strings[j]))  // check if the two strings are equal
            System.out.println("The two strings are the same"); // SOP
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The start value for j should be (i + 1), not 0. There is no need to repeat any comparisons (and we know that we want to ignore i == j).

Comment: Is equals as the same as equalsIgnoreCase ?

Comment: @user3479194 No equals will return false if it compares an upper case string with a lower case string ex: AAA and aaa return false. However, equalsIgnoreCase will return true for comparing aaa and AAA

Comment: That's Right , The Names with a & A are two different Names . Thanks my problem Solved just now :)

Comment: No prob, please mark it as solved if you don't have any other questions :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a faster solution. We do not repeat any comparisons, and we automatically avoid comparing a string to itself.

```
for (int i=0; i< strings.length;i++) {
  for (int j= i + 1; j<strings.length;j++) {
     if (strings[i].equals(strings[j]))
        System.out.println("The two strings are the same");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,my temp3 has only two Name , but when I put m<3 & n <3 we have no answer , why ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without any explicit looping by using a `Set`:

```
if (temp3.length != new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(temp3)).size()) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
}
```

This works by checking if the final `Set` has the same number of entries as the array. If not, then there must have been a duplicate. (This is actually an instance of the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). I find it kind of funny that such a simple deduction needs a special name!)